# Python: Removing spaces from list objects

Tags: python, list

I have a list of objects appended from a mysql database and contain spaces. I wish to remove the spaces such as below, but the code im using doesnt work?

```
hello = ['999 ',' 666 ']

k = []

for i in hello:
    str(i).replace(' ','')
    k.append(i)

print k
```

Comment: Or fix the type of the database field ;-)

Comment: @ChristopheD: What database "field" type forces **leading** spaces? Better to fix the developer and tester.

Comment: @Johan Machin: I did mis the leading space on the second entry (judged a little too fast, oops)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable (meaning that their data cannot be modified) so the replace method doesn't modify the string - it returns a new string. You could fix your code as follows:

```
for i in hello:
    j = i.replace(' ','')
    k.append(j)
```

However a better way to achieve your aim is to use a list comprehension. For example the following code removes leading and  trailing spaces from every string in the list using [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
hello = [x.strip(' ') for x in hello]
```

Comment: +1 for strip.  -1 for replace(' ','')

Comment: OP wants to remove *all* spaces, not just trailers, so why -1 for `replace(' ','')`?  None of the 'strip' methods, much less the other [built-in str methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), do the job (ignoring Rube Goldbergs like `''.join(s.split())`).

Comment: Ah, so it isn't a text field that used spaces to separate thousands, millions, etc. that is defined as text because it might contain the occasional keyword?  OK, I missed that.

Comment: The second element in the OP's list has 5 chars. Leading and trailing space

Comment: Since the example shows no internal spaces, I'm suspicious about removing internal spaces.

Answer (score 21):

List comprehension `[num.strip() for num in hello]` is the fastest.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> hello = ['999 ',' 666 ']

>>> t1 = lambda: map(str.strip, hello)
>>> timeit.timeit(t1)
1.825870468015296

>>> t2 = lambda: list(map(str.strip, hello))
>>> timeit.timeit(t2)
2.2825958750515269

>>> t3 = lambda: [num.strip() for num in hello]
>>> timeit.timeit(t3)
1.4320335103944899

>>> t4 = lambda: [num.replace(' ', '') for num in hello]
>>> timeit.timeit(t4)
1.7670568718943969
```

Comment: `list(map(str.strip, hello))` doesn't make a whole lot of sense since `map` returns a list itself.

Comment: @ChristopheD: In Python 3, map does not return a list.

Answer (score 13):

```
result = map(str.strip, hello)
```

Comment: There is no need to use the `lambda`; instead you could use: `result = map(str.strip(), hello)`.  However, As mentioned by @riza, in Python 3 map returns an iterator instead of a list. So best practice would be `result = list(map(str.strip(), hello))`.

Comment: Note that (in Python 3 at least) you must say `map(str.strip, mylist)` not `map(str.strip(), mylist)`.

Answer (score 7):

String methods return the modified string.

```
k = [x.replace(' ', '') for x in hello]
```

Answer (score 4):

Presuming that you don't want to remove internal spaces:

```
def normalize_space(s):
    """Return s stripped of leading/trailing whitespace
    and with internal runs of whitespace replaced by a single SPACE"""
    # This should be a str method :-(
    return ' '.join(s.split())

replacement = [normalize_space(i) for i in hello]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for element in range(0,len(hello)):
      d[element] = hello[element].strip()
```

Comment: In addition to your code, please explain why your answer works and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

replace() does not operate in-place, you need to assign its result to something. Also, for a more concise syntax, you could supplant your for loop with a one-liner: `hello_no_spaces = map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''), hello)`