# How to remove whitespace in a list

Tags: python, list

I can't remove my whitespace in my list.

```
invoer = "5-9-7-1-7-8-3-2-4-8-7-9"
cijferlijst = []

for cijfer in invoer:
    cijferlijst.append(cijfer.strip('-'))
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work. I already made a list from my string and seperated everything but the `"-"` is now a `""`.

```
filter(lambda x: x.strip(), cijferlijst)
filter(str.strip, cijferlijst)
filter(None, cijferlijst)
abc = [x.replace(' ', '') for x in cijferlijst]
```

Comment: `cijferlijst = filter(lambda x: x.strip(), cijferlijst)`

Comment: Why you just don't split the text with `-`?

Comment: Why not this `cijferlijst = invoer.split("-")`? Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MattCremeens You actually did it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Try that:

```
>>> ''.join(invoer.split('-'))
'597178324879'
```

Comment: Why not `replace`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the numbers in string without `-`, use [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) as:

```
>>> string_list = "5-9-7-1-7-8-3-2-4-8-7-9"
>>> string_list.replace('-', '')
'597178324879'
```

If you want the numbers as `list` of numbers, use [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> string_list.split('-')
['5', '9', '7', '1', '7', '8', '3', '2', '4', '8', '7', '9']
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like the following question:
[Python: Removing spaces from list objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232953/python-removing-spaces-from-list-objects)

The answer being to use `strip` instead of `replace`. Have you tried

```
abc = x.strip(' ') for x in x
```