# Can't seem to remove all empty strings and blank strings from a list?

Tags: python

I have a long list of information scraped from the Billboard Hot 100 page which I am trying to distill into just songs and artists. However, I can't seem to remove all the empty parts as well as points in the list that are just blank spaces. '' and ' '

I have tried everything I can find on here with regards to the filter function as well as other options people have suggested. My initial attempt was using the included code, which worked for the first part of the list but for some reason never finishes and always stops part way.

```
for y in parse:
    if y == "":
        parse.remove("")
    elif y == " ":
        parse.remove(" ")
```

I would expect to be receiving a list with no '' or ' ' by themselves, but only the first part of the list is affected.

Comment: Post a sample of `parse`.

Comment: You are modifying the list as you iterating over it, this will cause items to be skipped. You should use something like a list comprehension or filter for this. For example: `parse = [p for p in parse if p not in ['', ' ']]`

Comment: I guess this can do the job: ```clean_list = [row for row in parse if row.strip()]```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Removing spaces from list objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232953/python-removing-spaces-from-list-objects)

Answer (score 4):

This will do the job:

```
>>> dirty =['1',' ', '', '2','3','4']
>>> clean = [row for row in dirty if row.strip()]
>>> clean
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>>
```

Comment: I see what you did there. *dirty*

Comment: the `if row.strip()` bit is clever

Answer (score 2):

Using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
parse = ['a', ' ', 'b', 'c', '', 'd']
```

**Python 2.x**:

```
print(filter(str.strip, parse))
```

**Python 3.x**:

```
print(list(filter(str.strip, parse)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**EDIT**:

To remove the empty spaces within the elements, let's say:

```
parse = ['a ', ' ', ' b', 'c', '', 'd ']
```

Using [`map()`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

**Python 2.x**:

```
print(map(str.strip, filter(str.strip, parse)))
```

**Python 3.x**:

```
print(list(map(str.strip, filter(str.strip, parse))))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont modify the list you are iterating over.

Assuming parse is like

```
parse=[1,' ', '', 2,3,4]
```

you can do something like

```
parse_fix=[]
for y in parse:
    if y!='' and y!=' ': parse_fix.append(y)
```

then `parse_fix` will be the list you want

the short version might look like this

```
parse=[y for y in parse if y!='' and y!=' ']
```

Comment: Can't say because we're not sure of how exactly is the `parse` list in OP's case.

Comment: @DirtyBit well thats what the "assuming" bit was for

Comment: This worked! With one caveat - it needs to use 'and' instead of 'or'. Still not sure I understand why just modifying the list doesn't work, but now I know.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
list1 = ["1 ", "", " ", "3", "  4", "       ",""]
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x.strip() ]
```

output list2:

```
['1 ', '3', '  4']
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer I gave, @Frenchy.

Comment: yes ,just a problem of bandwith so i let you the paternity!! and i upvote to you

Comment: :-P Thanks, @Frenchy